# How can I force Firefox to log everything verbosely?

Tags: firefox

I'm trying to find out why Firefox keeps crashing on my machine. I looked at the crash dump, but I wasn't able to get enough information to find the bug.

Firefox has a `--MOZ_LOG` argument that allows the user to specify the logging level per module: for example `--MOZ_LOG=foo:5,bar:5` tells modules `foo` and `bar` to both log verbosely. However, since I don't know which module the bug originates in, this hasn't helped me so far. I tried `--MOZ_LOG=*:5`, but that caused nothing to be printed.

Comment: I don't think you would get much more detail than the crash dump?  I assume the process crashes?  As a general rule, I typically download Procdump, run `procdump -ma -i C:\dumps` having created C:\dumps. Then use WinDbg. It might provide some extra context to run Process Monitor up to the point it crashes, or even run/attach to Firefox under APIMonitor.  I would probably try and disable all third party modules from loading as much as possible.

Comment: Does it crash if you start it in safe mode?

Answer (score 2):

As per https://stackoverflow.com/q/62220211/388010 and https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/master/widget/windows/nsdefs.h `MOZ_LOG=all:5` might be what you are looking for.

Comment: It doesn't work.