# Obtain verbose log from all firefox modules

Tags: linux, firefox

I'm trying to get logs from FireFox browser.

I have found in [different answer](https://superuser.com/a/1642781/384802), that "module" `all` should be used in `MOZ_LOG` when all modules should be logged.

When I run FireFox and then I close it, several files are created in specified directory but all of them are empty:

```
$ firefox --MOZ_LOG_FILE=/tmp/vvo/vv --MOZ_LOG=all:5
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.

$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 vaclav vaclav 0 Jul 18 19:49 vv.child-1.moz_log
-rw-r--r-- 1 vaclav vaclav 0 Jul 18 19:49 vv.child-2.moz_log
-rw-r--r-- 1 vaclav vaclav 0 Jul 18 19:49 vv.child-3.moz_log
-rw-r--r-- 1 vaclav vaclav 0 Jul 18 19:50 vv.child-4.moz_log
-rw-r--r-- 1 vaclav vaclav 0 Jul 18 19:50 vv.child-5.moz_log
-rw-r--r-- 1 vaclav vaclav 0 Jul 18 19:50 vv.child-6.moz_log
-rw-r--r-- 1 vaclav vaclav 0 Jul 18 19:49 vv.moz_log
```

But If I use the `nsHttp` module, then it logs something:

```
$ firefox --MOZ_LOG_FILE=/tmp/vvo/vv --MOZ_LOG=nsHttp:5
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.

$ ls -lh
total 7.2M
-rw-r--r-- 1 vaclav vaclav 2.2K Jul 18 19:52 vv.child-1.moz_log
-rw-r--r-- 1 vaclav vaclav    0 Jul 18 19:52 vv.child-2.moz_log
-rw-r--r-- 1 vaclav vaclav  24K Jul 18 19:52 vv.child-3.moz_log
-rw-r--r-- 1 vaclav vaclav    0 Jul 18 19:52 vv.child-4.moz_log
-rw-r--r-- 1 vaclav vaclav    0 Jul 18 19:52 vv.child-5.moz_log
-rw-r--r-- 1 vaclav vaclav    0 Jul 18 19:52 vv.child-6.moz_log
-rw-r--r-- 1 vaclav vaclav 7.2M Jul 18 19:52 vv.moz_log
```

It seems like the `all` module does not work with Mozilla Firefox 102.0.1 but I'm not able to find any other way how to enable logging for all modules.